# Relace newline with hyphen if followed by search text

Tags: php, replace

I am trying to search a text for a specified value and if found, join it to the previous line with a hyphen.

This my code

```
$text = "ABC01
ABC02
ABC03
ABC04
ABC05
ABC06
";
$text = explode("\n",str_replace("\r", "", $text));
$text = array_filter($text, 'trim');
$previous = "";

foreach ($text as $line) {

    if ($line == 'ABC04') {
        echo $previous." - ".$line;
        echo '<br>';
    }
    else{
        echo $line;echo '<br>';
    }

$previous = $line;
}
```

result is

```
ABC01
ABC02
ABC03
ABC03 - ABC04
ABC05
ABC06
```

but **ABC03** on 3rd line

***I want this result***

```
ABC01
ABC02
ABC03 - ABC04
ABC05
ABC06
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe this is a solution?
I use array_search to find the value key.
The I add the value to the previous value.
Then I unset the found key and implode the array.

```
$text = "ABC01
ABC02
ABC03
ABC04
ABC05
ABC06";
$text = explode("\n",str_replace("\r", "", $text));
$text = array_filter($text, 'trim');

$key = array_search("ABC04", $text);

$text[$key-1] .= " - " . $text[$key];
Unset($text[$key]);

Echo implode("<br>\n", $text);
```

https://3v4l.org/WrTCZ

Edit; I see that indenting the code caused a problem at 3v4l. 
Replaced the link to not indented

Comment: its works fine but i  want foreach loop with if condition thanks

because if condition is changeable

Comment: Ex like $line == $previous

Comment: Any code is changeable. That is no reason loop. Just change the string value in array_search and you can change it however much you want

Comment: if text is int value  if( ($line - $previous) == $somevalue )

Comment: @ASang you need to explain why you want to loop. This is not a problem that needs to be looped. All looping does is make it slower, so why do you so desperately want it? The code I posted does exactly what you want. It can be changed. It can handle multiple inputs with a small change.

Comment: for example   ($line - $previous)   multiple condition like  5, 15, 25, 35.. ex...

Comment: I'm not doing it. Your question was strings that needed to be compared. Now you show up with something else. What's next? You need help to open a file and read the strings, no sorry integers? I'm done here

Answer (score 0):

Here is a foreach that works. But I am uncclear about what you really is trying to do.

```
foreach ($text as $line) {

    if ($line == 'ABC03') {
        echo $line.' - ';
    }
    else{
        echo $line;
        echo '<br>';
    }

   if ($line != 'ABC04')
       $previous = $line;
   }
}
```

Comment: ok but my Q is **$line == 'ABC04' **  because  after found ABC04

Comment: join previous line

Answer (score 0):

This one works too. It is simple

```
foreach ($text as $line) {

    if ($line == 'ABC03') {
        echo $line.' - ';
    } else {
        echo $line.'<br>';
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

For me an obvious problem is encountered when he searched value doesn't have a previous element -- therefore joining with a hyphen is unnecessary.

Because this task only requires a line within the text to have its preceeding newline character replaced with space-hyphen-space, this [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/352329) is most directly solved with a solitary `preg_replace()` call.  Ditch all of that other clumsy processing and looping.

- `\R+` will match one or more newline sequence of characters.
- `(?=...)` is a lookahead -- to ensure the the sought literal characters are found

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/BEloJ))

```
echo preg_replace(
         '/\R+(?=ABC04)/',
         ' - ',
         trim($text)
     );
```